# unable to create website and publish from team foundation service with git repository

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I am having trouble setting up a website on Azure and connecting it to my team foundation service account. The repository I am trying to use is a GIT repository.

Upon completing the Azure wizard, it returns a message stating that the account does not contain any repositories at all.

Are TFS-GIT repositories supported on Azure?

Answer (score 1):

TFService hosted Git repositories aren't yet supported (yet). You can still set up automated deployment though by using the hosted build servers and web deploy.

I've got a [blog post](http://www.richard-banks.org/2013/08/how-to-deploy-azure-website-from-git_21.html) that describes the steps and the MSBuild parameters to pass through.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Azure Websites support direct deploy from *public* Git repositories only. I had to choose the "private repo" option, which creates a secondary repository within Azure where you push to deploy. A little annoying on one hand, although it does let you control how often you actually want to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I had to work around this problem by cloning a TFS git repo and pulling upstream into a bitbucket one. A bit annoying not to have a single repo but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this post, it is now possible to deploy directly to an Azure Website from a hosted TFS build controller (visualstudio.com).

Configure it from the 'Deployment' options in the Azure management console of your website, NOT from the TFS instance. It will automatically create a build configuration for you.